# filepath is null in IFilespec Object

Tags: java, perforce, p4java

I am using p4java api's in my project. 
I am having a `IFileSpec` object which is not null. but when I do `fileSpec.toString()` it shows me null.
As per the p4java doc `fileSpec.toString()` method returns `AnnotatedPreferredPathString` which is defined to be *the path specified by (in order) the original path, the depot path, the client path, or the local path.*

wanted to check what could be the scenario where this path can be NULL ?

Note : I don't have direct access to perforce repo which I am using. I am executing my program on a separate host and I am just getting logs from there.

Comment: Can you include the actual code in your question?

Comment: private List<IFileRevisionData> getFileRevisionData(Map<IFileSpec, List<IFileRevisionData>> dataMap,
   String depotPath)  {

  for (Map.Entry<IFileSpec, List<IFileRevisionData>> data : dataMap.entrySet()) {

   String fileDepotPath = data.getKey().getDepotPathString();
   if(fileDepotPath == null) {
    System.out.println("Depot path is NULL for fileSpec : " + data.getKey() +  " and depothPath : " + depotPath);
   }

   if (fileDepotPath.equals(depotPath)) {
    return data.getValue();
   }
  }

  return Collections.emptyList();
 }